# Combine two select queries in one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables : history, video and user.
The two following queries display for each video the number of views for french users or for german users :

```
SELECT V.idVideo, COUNT(H.idVideo) AS nb_fr
FROM HISTORY H
INNER JOIN VIDEO V ON V.idVideo = H.idVideo
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.idUser = H.idUser
WHERE U.nationality = 'french'
GROUP BY H.idVideo
ORDER BY V.idVideo;
```

and

```
SELECT V.idVideo, COUNT(H.idVideo) AS nb_ge
FROM HISTORY H
INNER JOIN VIDEO V ON V.idVideo = H.idVideo
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.idUser = H.idUser
WHERE U.nationality = 'german'
GROUP BY H.idVideo
ORDER BY V.idVideo
```

But how combine this two queries to have only one ?
I would like something like that :

```
idVideo | nb_fr | nb_ge
-----------------------
    1   |   5   |   4
    2   |   3   |   6
    3   |   2   |   8
    4   |   3   |   3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT V.idVideo,
       COUNT(case when U.nationality = 'french' then H.idVideo end) AS nb_fr,
       COUNT(case when U.nationality = 'german' then H.idVideo end) AS nb_ge
FROM HISTORY H
INNER JOIN VIDEO V ON V.idVideo = H.idVideo
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.idUser = H.idUser
WHERE U.nationality in ('french', 'german')
GROUP BY V.idVideo
ORDER BY V.idVideo;
```

Note the change to `GROUP BY V.idVideo`, because that's the selected column.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT V.idVideo,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN  U.nationality = 'french' THEN 1 END) AS nb_fr,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN  U.nationality = 'german' THEN 1 END) AS nb_ge
FROM HISTORY H
INNER JOIN VIDEO V ON V.idVideo = H.idVideo
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.idUser = H.idUser
GROUP BY H.idVideo
ORDER BY V.idVideo
```

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT H.idVideo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN U.nationality = 'french' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nb_fr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN U.nationality = 'german' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nb_ge
FROM HISTORY H INNER JOIN
     USER U 
     ON U.idUser = H.idUser
GROUP BY H.idVideo
ORDER BY H.idVideo;
```

Also note that the query can be simplified.  The `JOIN` to `VIDEO` is probably not needed (assuming that `idVideo` is unique, which is a very reasonable assumption).

Also, the `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` should use the same column reference.

Comment: This should never have been posted.  Did you not see the other two answers?

Comment: Actually in second glance I see he Gordon avoided the select from `VIDEO` which seems unnecessary , so his answer is fine :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @sagi OK then I partially retract my above comment.  For the record, I upvoted Gordon twice yesterday :-)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Oracle 11.1, you can use the PIVOT operation:

```
select idvideo, nb_fr, nb_ge
from   ( select h.idvideo, u.nationality
         from   history h inner join user u on h.iduser = u.iduser
       )
pivot  ( count(*) for nationality in ('french' as nb_fr, 'german' as nb_ge) )
order by idvideo
;
```